# Select entity based on session value

Tags: php, symfony

I got two entities. One is a WebshopItem entity, the other one is a WebshopPrice entity.
Each time, you are creating a WebshopItem, you are also filling in 3 WebshopPrices. The WebshopPrices are 3 currencies (EUR, USD and GBP).

Based on the currency you selected (and is saved in your session) I want to display the currency you selected. So, if you picked EUR, I of course want to display the EUR price.

What's the general way of doing this in symfony? Should I use a twig extension which returns the price from the WebshopItem object, based on what's in your session? Should I already filter the WebshopPrices from the database?

Looking forward to your best solutions. Thanks!

Entity/WebshopItem.php

```
class WebshopItem
{
   /**
   * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
   */
   private $prices;

   etc....
}
```

Entity/WebshopItemPrice.php

```
class WebshopItemPrice
{

   /**
   * @var integer
   */
   private $id;

   /**
   * @var string
   */
   private $currency;

   /**
   * @var string
   */
   private $price;

   private $webshopItem;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can use an [entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) too, but in that case you'll need to override the default resolver to get the session in your listener:

**src/Your/GreatBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
doctrine.orm.default_entity_listener_resolver:
        class: Your\GreatBundle\Listener\EntityListenerResolver
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

**src/Your/GreatBundle/Listener/EntityListenerResolver**

```
namespace Your\GreatBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\EntityListenerResolver as EntityListenerResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class EntityListenerResolver implements EntityListenerResolverInterface
{
    private $instances = [];
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function clear($className = null)
    {
        if ($className === null) {

            $this->instances = [];

            return;
        }

        if (isset($this->instances[$className = trim($className, '\\')])) {

            unset($this->instances[$className]);
        }
    }

    public function register($object)
    {
        if ( ! is_object($object)) {

            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('An object was expected, but got "%s".', gettype($object)));
        }

        $this->instances[get_class($object)] = $object;
    }

    public function resolve($className)
    {
        if (isset($this->instances[$className = trim($className, '\\')])) {

            return $this->instances[$className];
        }

        // Here we are injecting the entire container to the listeners
        return $this->instances[$className] = new $className($this->container);
    }
}
```

---

You might listen to the [Doctrine's postLoad event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html) in a service injected with the user's session:

**src/Your/GreatBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    price.listener:
        class: Your\GreatBundle\Listener\PriceListener
        arguments: [@session]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

**src/Your/GreatBundle/Listener/PriceListener.php**

```
namespace Your\GreatBundle\Listener\PriceListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Your\GreatBundle\Entity\WebshopItem;

class PriceListener
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof WebshopItem) {

            $currency = $this->session->get('currency', 'EUR');
            $entity->setCurrency(currency);
        }
    }
}
```

**src/Your/GreatBundle/Entity/WebshopItem.php**

```
namespace Your\GreatBundle\Entity;

class WebshopItem
{
   ...

   // You don't need to persist this...
   private $currency = 'EUR';

   public function setCurrency($currency)
   {
        $this->currency = $currency;
   }

   public function getPrice()
   {
        foreach ($this->prices as $price) {

            if ($price->getCurrency() === $this->currency) {

                return ($price->getPrice();
            }
        }

        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Am I correct when I assume that the PriceListener is called every time data is retrieved from Doctrine? To me, that seems like some overhead. Or ain't it that worse?

Comment: Ain't that worse... Doctrine events are designed for this, take Doctrine Extensions as an example (https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Timestampable/TimestampableListener.php). Doctrine events are a great way to decouple things. If you want to avoid using the postLoad event, then you should develop a WebshopItem manager (or repository) and use it every time you need to retrieve one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can query WebshopItem joined with WebshopItemPrice `WHERE` WebshopItemPrice.currency = $variableFromSesion. For example:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('WebshopItem, WebshopItemPrice')
    ->leftJoin('WebshopItemPrice.prices', 'WebshopItemPrice')
    ->where('WebshopItemPrice.currency = :currency')
    ->setParameter('currency', $variableFromSesion)
```

Where `$variableFromSesion` is a current user currency stored in session. After executing that query (by `getResult()` ) you can get price by calling $webshopItem->getPrices() - this should return only one result

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not about how to retrieve the data but what to use to do it. Since this depends on the Request object you should go with something service-ish. If you're sure you'll never never use this elsewhere, then go with the twig extension. If your backend code would use it too then use a service, say MyPricePickerService (and get that in the twig extension). Note on twig extension that I cannot find anything that warrants that a new instance is created for every scope, so upon every call to this operation you should use the injected Container (so not a cached Request, or a previous instance of MyPricePickerService)!

Comment: Sounds interesting. How would that Service looks like basically? I mean, I got an overview page with 10 items. Is the service handling WebshopItem per WebshopItem or is it handling all 10 at once?

Comment: Item-by-item. It should not do more than to return the appropriate price for an item with something like public function getItemDefaultPrice(WebshopItem $item). If you're troubled about the loading of prices: pre-loading should be done either via eager-loading that relationship, or explicitly pre-loading the entities in the controller.